# Не работает async.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

Нужен асинхронный вызов функции, использовал async.each, но он не дает того, что нужно. Данный метод вычисляет параллельно,из-за чего приложение работает не корректно.

```js
async.each(body, 
            function (address, callback){
              console.log(address);
              repository = address.slice(address.lastIndexOf('/')+1, address.length);

              child_process.exec('git clone '+ address, 
                function(err, stdout, stderr){   
                  
                console.log(stderr);
                console.log(repository);               
                  child_process.exec('git log --pretty=format:"%ae [%an]"',
                  {cwd: repository},
                  function(err, stdout, stderr){ 
                  console.log(stderr); 
                  console.log(stdout);          
                    child_process.exec('rd '+repository+' /s /q', function(err, stdout, stderr){
                      console.log(stderr);
                      callback();           

                    });
                    
                                         
                  }
                )})
              },
                function(err){              
                  if( err ) {      
                       console.log('A file failed to process');
                   } else {
                   console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
                 }
                
              }                         

            );
```

нужен подобный метод, но без паралельного вычисления

Comment: Вроде `async.series`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async.eachSeries(hugeArray, function iterator(item, callback) {
    if (inCache(item)) {
        callback(null, cache[item]); // if many items are cached, you'll overflow
    } else {
        doSomeIO(item, callback);
    }
}, function done() {
    //...
});
```